# Spark structured streaming integration with RabbitMQ

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I want to use Spark structured streaming to aggregate data which is consumed from RabbitMQ.
I know there is official spark structured streaming integration with apache kafka, and I was wondering if there exists some integration with RabbitMQ as well?
Since I'm not able to switch the existing messaging system (RabbitMQ), I thought of using kafka-connect to move the data between the messaging systems (Rabbit to kafka) and then use Spark structured streaming.

Does anyone knows a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq) custom RabbitMQ receiver seems to available if you're open to exploring Spark Streaming rather than Structured Streaming.